# Trying to access boolean variable from all instances of a class

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, checkbox

I'm trying to print the boolean value of check boxes in Tkinter, I've created a minimal reproduced example that resembles my original code.

It may look like threading is not needed, but it is needed for my actual project.

Anyway I'm just trying to access the checkbox variable for each instance of class `checkbutton_gen`

Here's the code:

```
import threading
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class checkbutton_gen(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.checkbuttonvalue = BooleanVar(value=False)
        
    def run(self):
        self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(root,onvalue=True,offvalue=False,textvariable=self.checkbuttonvalue)
        self.checkbutton.pack()

for count in range(10):
    thread = checkbutton_gen()
    thread.start()

Button(root, text='Check to see of checkboxes are ticked', command=lambda:check()).pack()

def check():
    for checkbox in checkbutton_gen.checkbuttonvalue:
        print(checkbutton_gen.checkbuttonvalue)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's the error i'm getting:

```
    for checkbox in checkbutton_gen.checkbuttonvalue:
AttributeError: type object 'checkbutton_gen' has no attribute 'checkbuttonvalue'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the created instances. There are 2 possibilities I can think of:
**global variable** ([considered bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil/19158418#19158418))

```
checkboxes = []
for count in range(10):
    thread = checkbutton_gen()
    checkboxes.append(thread)

def check():
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        print(checkbox.checkbuttonvalue)
```

**Static variable**

```
class checkbutton_gen(threading.Thread):
    instances = []
    def __init__(self):      
       self.instances.append(self) # or checkbutton_gen.instances.append(self)
       ...

def check():
    for checkbox in checkbutton_gen.instances:
        print(checkbox.checkbuttonvalue)
```

Comment: The first solution couldn't get the correct value of checkbutton, the second solution would even raise `NameError`.

Comment: It should be `self.instances.append(self)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the class but you should call the instance of that class.

I think it should be something like this:

```
instance = checkbutton_gen()
for checkbox in instance.checkbuttonvalue:
```